# Rails model "before_filter"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I know that before_filter is only for controllers in Rails, but I would like something like this for a model: any time a method in my model is called, I'd like to run a method that determines whether the called method should run. Conceptually, something like this:

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_filter :confirm_company

  def confirm_company
    if self.parent.thing == false?
      return false
    end
  end

  def method1
    #do stuff
  end

end
```

So when I call @website.method1, it will first call confirm_company, and if I return false, will not run method1. Does Rails have functionality like this? I hope i'm just missing out on something obvious here...

Comment: You mean [Active Record Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview)?

Comment: Yes, a callback is what I need, I guess. But none of the available callbacks can do what I'm after. I'm not saving, validating, intializing... I am calling a method.

Comment: you could use a proxy object and delegate to the model if your condition is met

Comment: apneadiving - can you provide some more detail? Not sure what you mean...

Comment: see http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/05/understanding-ruby-and-rails-proxy-patter-delegation-and-basicobject/

Comment: Thanks for the link: fascinating technique! While it would provide a more-containerized solution, it would still require me to touch every model method to redirect to the proxy object. I'm looking for something a little more hands-off, if it exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class MyModel
    extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
    define_model_callbacks :do_stuff

    before_do_stuff :confirm

    def do_stuff
        run_callbacks :do_stuff do
            #your code
        end
    end

    def confirm
        #confirm
    end
end
```

I'm really not sure this will work, but you can try it, as I really dont have time now. Take a look at that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html

Comment: This runs exactly as you stated. It requires me to touch every model, but it's a very clean solution, all things considered. Thanks very much!

Comment: Cool :) You can maybe think about extracting stuff into modules if you have recurrent patterns across your models. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a gem just for this.

You can plug this in any ruby class, and do something like in the controller.

```
before_action :foobar, on: [:foo]
```

https://github.com/EdmundLeex/action_callback

Comment: nice but technically a method in model is not an action, it could be `before_method`