# Convert comma to dot for numbers before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to fix price field before Rails does it? I'm getting this error:

> `undefined method`before_filter' for Class:0x007fdddc1549d0>`

Code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_filter :update_fields

  private

    def update_fields
        self.price = self.price.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
        # getting this results if called in "before_save"
        # 5.77 => 5.77
        # 5,15 => 5.00
    end
end
```

Comment: `before_filter` only works in Controllers. Maybe you'd be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398282/rails-model-before-filter ?

Comment: before_filter is for controllers. Check before_save or before_create

Comment: Thanks! Maybe there is some earlier function than "before_save"? price field is fixed until it calls the action.

Comment: Try with `before_create`.

Comment: Thanks! Still the same, but moved this action to controller and used before_action - now it works!

Comment: Regardless of whether you implement this in the model or the controller, you might want to consider using `I18n.l(price)` instead of `price.to_s.gsub ...`--that communicates your intentions more clearly (if you intention is, in fact, to store the numbers in the format of a different locale).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have solved this moving code to the controller:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fix_fields

  private
  def fix_fields
      if params[:item].present?
        params[:item][:price] = params[:item][:price].to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
      end
  end
```

Now if user enters:
`5,75` saves `5.75`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem directly inside the model, without needing the before_filter callback inside the controller:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :update_fields

  private
  def update_fields
    [:field_1, :field_2, :field_3].each {|k|
      self[k.to_sym] = self.attributes_before_type_cast[k.to_s].gsub(',', '.').to_f
    }
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!